# How should I re-size images on webpage?

Tags: html, css, firefox, lag

I have some high resolution images and have to re-size it to be smaller and animate it on webpage.
I do not want to re-szie it on image editor because I want to have high resolution on wide monitors.
I have tried several methods to re-size the images, but there still performance issue on Firefox.
While the re-sized images is animated, the CPU rise to 90%,and memory take up to 500mb.
The below methods didn't help improve the performance, what is the common best way to re-size images?

```
<img id='picture' src='picture.png'>
#picture{width:50px;height:50px}
```

Or

```
<div id='picture'></div>
#picture{display:block;width:50px;height:50px;background:url('picture.png');background-size:100%}
```

Or

```
<div id='picture'></div>
#picture{display:block;background:url('picture.png');background-size:100%;-moz-transform:scale(0.5);}
```

Comment: I mean animate it using css animation keyframes or transitions,I do sometimes forget to accept answers,is it important?

Comment: If you don't give credit to correct answers it makes people less likely to answer your questions because of your perceived lack of participation in the community.

Comment: okay no problem, I will do it. Sometimes I'm just too busy on my own works, but people gave me lots of helps here,I should've give them credits.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the site?  Just how big are these images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so try this(THIS IS EXAMPLE THAT I TEST IT AND GIVE ANSWER)

```
HTML  


<button id="go1">» Animate Block1</button>
  <div id="block1"></div>
```

CSS

```
div { 
    background-image:url(Desert.jpg); 
    width:542px;
    height:351px;
    border:2px solid green;
  }
```

SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#go1").click(function(){
      $("#block1").animate( { width:"1004px" }, { queue:false, duration:3000 } )
         .animate( { height:"687px" }, { queue:false, duration:3000 } )   
    });
  });
```

use "jquery-latest.js" plugin too.
just have a 1 problem that is resize() an image but no completely .!I try to solve that!

Comment: I've just tried it,still lag. I have an image like 1004px * 687px, but I want to show it 542px*351px on webpage, but when I animate it, it lag like hell on firefox, but the designer say do not resize his images on image editor, what could I do?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best option here is to pretty much do what you've already done:

#### HTML

```
<div class="huge_image">
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.huge_image {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: url("/images/massive_image.jpg");
  background-size: 500px 300px;
}
```

If the performance is really that bad, you could use create a half-sized version for those without retina displays and only serve the full version to retina-capable clients.  Look into [retina.js](http://retinajs.com) for an easy way to do this.

Comment: I almost need to re-size the image into half,it don't works,with couple of these images re-size,cpu rise so much in firefox. But then I have to make 2 versions of the website, and relayout it on a wide monitor?

Comment: Because retina displays have the same number of "css pixels" as non-retina displays, there's no change the layout when serving higher resolution images.